# Calling a default servlet first in Java web application

Tags: java, servlets

I want my `SampleServlet` to be called first whenever my java web application is accessed in this manner :

`http://server:8080/appname/`

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 6):

Use a [Servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28959/filters.htm) to call your Servlet.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make a servlet your homepage then this worked for me on http://feelitlive.com/

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>homepage</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

...

<servlet>
    <description>Shows stuff on the homepage</description>
    <display-name>Homepage Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>HomepageServlet</servlet-name>        
    <servlet-class>com.cantorva.gigcalendar.servlets.HomepageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

...

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomepageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/homepage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That means that that users arriving at your application via the URL you specified will be welcomed by your servlet. It also creates an alias for the homepage at "/homepage" but you don't have to use that.

If you want to run some code on start-up then [asalamon74's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669108/calling-a-default-servlet-first-in-java-web-application/669113#669113) looks right.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean but you need to map your servlet to "/"

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your aim, but web application initialization can be achieved by ServletContextListener:

```
public class AppListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // place your code here
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }
}
```

and later in web.xml:

```
<web-app>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        package.AppListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
...
</web-app>
```

Comment: This is invoked once, during the application's life cycle. The poster asked for something that is accessed once per request.

Comment: imho, the question isn't clear that you can vote it down as off-topic. I interpreted the question to mean "when the user turns up" and to mean displaying a servlet generated page rather than running code. Its a bad question, and a helpful answer whether they match is undecipherable.

Comment: erickson: Yes, I know it's invoked once and not once per request. The question was not clear, that's why I started my answer as "Not sure what is your aim".

Comment: In fact, I understood the question as once-when-the-application-starts (which was what I was looking for), and now I see it has double interpretation. So the answer is valid, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run code on start-up indeed [asalamon74's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669108/calling-a-default-servlet-first-in-java-web-application/669113#669113) should be fine. If you have a legacy situation and you must use a servlet, the parameter load-on-startup can do the trick for you:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>SampleServlet</display-name>
    <description>Sample Servlet</description>
    <servlet-class>...</servlet-class>
    <init-param>...</init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

The load-on-startup tag specifies that the servlet should be loaded automatically when the web application is started; the number value just gives a loading order to those loading on startup. If no  value is specified, the servlet will be loaded when the container decides it needs to be loaded - typically on it's first access.